# WebSocket Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, p2p

I try to make a P2P chat using websocket.

Locally, the installation works, but in production, the console shows this error message:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://mysite.com/8080' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Here is the code of the local server, which works:

```
const Socket = require("websocket").server
const http = require("http")

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {})

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 8080")
})

const webSocket = new Socket({ httpServer: server })
```

and the production

```
const Socket = require("websocket").server

const https = require("https")

const server = https.createServer((req, res) => {})

server.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("Listening on port 8080")
})

const webSocket = new Socket({ httpServer: server })
```

Also the JS code

```
 const webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080")
```

```
 const webSocket = new WebSocket("wss://mysite.com/8080")
```

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: Why is your path `/8080` in production. This looks like a bug

Comment: It's not a bug, I tought is was the right path. The server is listening on this port on localhost. To make it work online I changed the first part of the path by adding my website address, but what should be following, if not the port?

Comment: Is your app actually https? Wss means secure which i doubt you are doing

Comment: @user20197852 anything after `/` is not a port. The host and port is separated with a `:`

Comment: Asad Awadia Yes my site is https. Evert I tried with a : then with a / but result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
ws://127.0.0.1:8080
^^            ^

wss://mysite.com/8080
^^^             ^
```

See the difference? On the local server you used `ws` which means unencrypted websocket. On the remote server you used `wss` which means websocket with HTTPS. If your server isn't set up to handle encrypted HTTPS connections then the connection will fail.

Additionally, the port number comes after `:` - by writing `/` you said to use the default port number, which is 443 for HTTPS and 80 for HTTP, and the `/8080` is the path, which I think your server doesn't care about.

Comment: in my situation this isnt based on this see my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76748567/cant-connect-to-websocket-server